# Applying for expedited US B1/B2 Visa

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I have been rejected once for US B1/B2 Visa around 1 year ago.
Here's is how it went.

> Interviewer: What is your designation? Me: Member of technical staff.
>
> Interviewer: What is the purpose of your visit? Me: To attend some
>   business meetings and training workshop being done at headquarters of
>   our client (xxx)
>
> Interviewer: So why this can not be done over Telephonic / Video
>   conferencing calls? Me: Well difference in timezone doesn't permit
>   that. We have tried webex etc in past but it does not work as
>   efficiently as face to face discussions.
>
> Interviewer: Sorry. We can not permit you US visa this time.
>   (something like that, no reason given, he was just not convinced that my visit is critical)

This time my client company has sent me an invite letter again for more or less same agenda, and since I have to visit within a month I am planning for an expedited appointment.

Things which have changed:

1. My designation is now tech lead. I am expected to receive this training, discuss work timelines with client-side engineering teams and sync it with my team in India.
   I will have supporting documents stating this from both my client and my employer.
2. I have purchased a house in India, can I upload this as a supporting doc somewhere in my application to show my ties to my nation or it will be irrelevant and not recommended?

What are other do's and don'ts I should take care of in this entire process?

Some other questions I need suggestions for answers on are:

1. Same as last time, why this can't be done remotely. The answer is simply what I mentioned but I guess I need to frame it in correct words.
2. Why this could not be foreseen ahead and why you needed expedited application. Honest reason for this is client side management missed planning on this and now suddenly feel my presence in this planning is required.

Comment: What section of law did they cite in your refusal?  It doesn't reveal much, but it's better than nothing.  Owning a house is helpful, but there's no way to submit documents with your application. Bring them to the interview.

Comment: I am reading on the US travel docs website that when you expedite visa you get option to upload docs supporting your case?

Comment: I am not familiar with the expedited process, nor was I even aware of its existence before now, so you should trust what the website says and not what I said.  I do think evidence of homeownership is relevant, but it's hard to know for sure why you were refused before.  I don't think necessity of the visit is a criterion for business visas, but I could be wrong about that too.

Comment: What other criterion you think are good enough for business visa? Any business agendas u can suggest?